# What is the relationship of the following compounds?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

What is the relationship of these following compounds? My guess is they are constitutional isomers. However, a couple of people said that they are enantiomers of each other. Which one is correct?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are enantiomers. It may be difficult to see this in the way you drew it, but if you drew the structures in a proper decagon form, it may be more clear.

Think about it this way. If you were not given the stereoisomerism of the methoxy group, you would think they would be the same molecule by counting the carbons in each direction (you'll notice that methyl and methoxy groups are on carbon 6 and carbon 1 respectively).

Now, if you consider R or S configuration for the methoxy group, you'll see that they are enantiomers. This becomes clear when you apply Cahn–Ingold–Prelog priority rules to the carbon with the methoxy group.